# What is $H\left| \psi \right>$ with $\left| \psi \right> = \alpha\left| 0 \right> + \beta\left| 1 \right>$?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

I'm currently going through [Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing](https://www.thomaswong.net/introduction-to-classical-and-quantum-computing-1e3p.pdf), by Thomas Wong, and I'm struggling with exercise 2.29 (page 107):

> **Exercise 2.29.** Say $\left| \psi \right> = \alpha\left| 0 \right> + \beta\left| 1 \right>$ is a normalized quantum state, i.e., $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$.
>
> (a) Calculate $H\left| \psi \right>$.

Given the two following transformations the Hadamard gate does:

$$\begin{align}
H\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>)\\
H\left| 1 \right> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - \left| 1 \right>)
\end{align}$$

I did the following:

$$\begin{align}
H\left| \psi \right> &= \alpha H\left| 0 \right> + \beta H\left| 1 \right>\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>) + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0 \right> - \left| 1 \right>)\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right>  + \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right> + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> - \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right>\\
&= \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{\alpha - \beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right>
\end{align}$$

Though, the answer given at the back of the book (page 360) is (notice the $+$ sign):
$$\begin{align}
H\left| \psi \right> &= \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 1 \right>
\end{align}$$

Why is that? This is a simple exercise, yet I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your result is correct. The answer you quote from the book is wrong and probably a typo. You can quickly check by plugging in $\alpha=0,\beta=1$, in which case that answer results in $H|1\rangle = |+\rangle$. More generally I don't think that is even a valid quantum state.

Comment: @forky40 oh, well that explains it...

Comment: @forky40 I think you still should write this as an answer, should anyone stumble upon the same problem!

Comment: Just reached out to the author of the textbook to fix the mistake, hopefully they see my email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is correct and that is probably a typo in the textbook, as already mentioned in the comments.

Moreover, if you write down your state as $| \psi \rangle = \alpha | 0 \rangle + \beta | 1 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha
\\ 
\beta
\end{bmatrix}$ and the Hadamard gate as $H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$, then computing the result is straightforward:
$$
H | \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha
\\ 
\beta
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha + \beta
\\ 
\alpha - \beta
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\sqrt{2}} | 0 \rangle + \frac{\alpha - \beta}{\sqrt{2}} | 1 \rangle
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your result is correct. The answer you quote from the book is wrong and probably a typo. You can quickly check by plugging in α=0,β=1, in which case that answer results in $H|1\rangle = |+\rangle$. More generally that is not a valid quantum state - for example, set $\alpha=\beta=1/\sqrt{2}$ and the result will be $\sqrt{2}|+\rangle$.